# Jump to anchor in another page

Tags: angularjs

I want to be able to jump to an anchor in another page(Page B).

In page B, I have a list of items like below.

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items'>{{item}}</div>
```

I want the anchor to be in one of the items. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items'>
  <a href="#/pageB">{{item}}</a>
</div>
```

where `pageB` is the route attach to page B.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Maybe I didn't make my question clear: I want to be able to goto an anchor point in pageB from pageA. The anchor point is an item (in a list) in pageB.